Why did I get 32 "Variety Reviewer" badges?
It's good to see that the new Staging Ground badges have been added.
That being said, I got some weird notifications:

Apparently, I got 32 "Variety Reviewer" badges:

Does that mean I reviewed Staging Ground questions from 50+32=82 tags (I don't think I reviewed questions from 50*32=1600 distinct tags) or is this some sort of race condition because all these badges have been awarded at the same time? Or would I get two badges if there are 50 distinct tags where I reviewed 2 questions each?
Apart from that, it seems like the Steadfast Reviewer badge can be earned multiple times as well, specifically every 7 days. While that might be intended, it seems a bit excessive to award a silver badge every 7 days for a single review per day.
This looks like something is a bit off...

There should be a similar happening for "Steadfast reviewer" badge but I guess that one makes a bit more sense.

Yes, it seems like I can get that silver badge every 7 days which seems excessive. I'll add that.

Yes I know that's possible (I've reviewed 2173 posts in total since the start of the first beta) but it would still be a lot of distinct tags. It would be interesting to know how it's calculated.

... I wonder if it just starts counting from scratch after you last get the badge. I got 11. also, I also feel like that the "steadfast reviewer" badge is too easy to get.

Badge Overflow???

You've done 3000 reviews!? You are a machine.

@Gimby I participated in both betas so that was over a long time.

So new Staging Ground Badges went live today as part of Staging Ground Reviewer Motivation!
Why did you get 32 variety reviewer badges? Well, because you earned em!
The logic is essentially*

Find all reviewed posts for user
Group by tags
Get the ROW_NUMBER of each tag (i.e. 1 kotlin, 2 spring-boot, 3 intellij-idea, etc.)
Then look where the row_num mod 50 equals 0, meaning the 50th unique tag value is the reason for the grant.

In your 3,009 reviews across 2,198 distinct posts, you've seen 1,614 different tags across all those posts.
Tag frequency just has a long tail, so lots of distinct one off values help contribute to that total.

*Note - similar logic exists for the Steadfast Reviewer badge so I can confirm that it requires two distinct 7 day stretches, not 8 days, 9 days, etc.

In that case, I guess it's [status-by-design]. Thank you for the clarification.

I'd have thought having multiple tier badges (bronze, silver, gold) would be better, but not something I'd post an FR for.
